# Different Font Families on the same app?

Tags: android, android-layout

For my app I've tested it on two different phones! One with KitKat but using the lollipop theme and the second using lollipop version.

[image: KitKat Version]

[image: Lollipop Version]

They use font family sans-serif-light but the second (lollipop version) font it bolder?

How can I set it so its constant all around?

Comment: Provide your own font in the `assets` folder then retrieve it and set the typeface of your Views to that one.

Comment: Check if user has set different system font in any of device.

Comment: Frank but isn't sans-serif-light a regular font to use that comes with the OS? Shouldn't it work when its the same app with no other fonts to choose from within the app? Amit does setting different system fonts effect the apps font even though its set within the XML of the app? Also thank you Frank and Amit for getting back to me :)

Comment: No, but if you declare font in .xml than it will be applied to all devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use your own font in your app the device uses the system font and rooted devices can change their system font so here is what makes diffrent typefaces in diffrent devices. Just put your own font in assets folder and apply it to your textview, now they all seemes the same anywhere.

Comment: Great Amir! Was killing me as I didn't know what was wrong as I thought the font is available on all devices. Seems manufacturers have their own fonts too! Thanks guys!

Comment: Not only. Different Android OS versions could use different fonts (DROID, ROBOTO, ...).

Comment: @Frank thanks, much better way so in making the font in the assets folder and not assume all devices will have a certain font :). Lesson learned :)